# Changing a column data type from datetime to float

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, ddl

I have a table with a `float` column. All values in this column for all records are `NULL`.
I want to change the data type to `datetime`.

I executed the query:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER Column MyColumn DATETIME NULL
```

It works. But when I try to revert the changes by setting the data type to `float`:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER Column MyColumn FLOAT NULL
```

I get the exception:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to float is not allowed.
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Note that column MyColumn is null for all records.

Answer (score 8):

With no data in the column you can just drop it and add it again.

```
alter table MyTable drop column MyColumn;

go

alter table MyTable add MyColumn float;
```

If you have data in your column and it makes sense to convert the values to a float value you can rename the column, add a new column, move the data using `convert` and then drop the old column.

```
exec sp_rename 'MyTable.MyColumn', 'Temp_MyColumn', 'COLUMN';

go

alter table MyTable add MyColumn float;

go

update MyTable 
set MyColumn = convert(float, Temp_MyColumn) 
where Temp_MyColumn is not null;

go

alter table MyTable drop column Temp_MyColumn;
```